# Is there a method to pass styling props to an Emotion css`...` prop (React)?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm working within a very atomised structure using `@emotion/react` that splits components into several different files:

- `types.ts` - for types (shared between web and native)
- `styles.ts` - for styling (shared between web and native)
- `logic.ts` - any applicable logic (shared between web and native)
- `web.tsx` - the web component
- `native.tsx` - the React native component

In the styles.ts file, I'd have something like the below:

```
export const ElementWrapper = css`
  border: 1px solid red
`
```

In the `web.tsx` file, I'll compile the component in a way such as below:

```
import { ElementProps } from './types'
import { ElementWrapper } from './styles'

export const Element = ({ children, ...rest}: PropsWithChildren<ElementProps>) => {

  return (
    <SOME_ELEMENT css={ElementWrapper} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </SOME_ELEMENT>
  )
}
```

Is there any way to pass styling props to the `ElementWrapper` component in the current setup? For example, a `marginRight=false` style of prop that I could access in the `styles.ts` file?

I attempted to pass props to the `SOME_ELEMENT` component, but obviously they can't be passed through. It also appears there's no way to add further props to the css property of `SOME_ELEMENT`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make a wrapper function.

```
export const ElementWrapper = ({marginRight}) => css`
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: ${marginRight};
`

// ...

return (
  <SOME_ELEMENT css={ElementWrapper({marginRight: '5px'})} {...rest}>
    {children}
  </SOME_ELEMENT>
)
```